# The problem asks to return true for matching brackets and false for mismatched brackets

Tags: java

I need return true if brackets match and vice versa. I am pretty new and I need help.

For ex.

{} true

{{} false

Here is my code :

```
String left = "}";

String right = "{";

int LCount = 0;

int RCount = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < brackets.length(); i++)
{
    if(brackets.charAt(i) == right)
    {
        RCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(left)
        {
            LCount++;
        }
    }
}

if(LCount == RCount)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

I am getting a lot of syntax errors.

Comment: What "_syntax errors_" are you getting?

Comment: Comparing a char with a String `if(brackets.charAt(i) == right)`  - why not have `right` as a char?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution counts number of right brackets and left bracket. It will return true for "}{". Ideally, you can achieve the behavior with single counter like below.

```
int count=0;
for(int i = 0; i < brackets.length(); i++)
{
    if(brackets.charAt(i) == '{')
    {
        count++;
    }else {
      count --;
    }
    //number of left bracket is greater than right
    if(count<0) return false;
}
//check all opening bracket have a corresponding closing bracket
return count==0;
```

Comment: also for "}{" it should return false, but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: line 11 of this code (if(count<0) return false;) takes care of that

Answer (score 0):

Use the char datatype for left and right

```
*String left = "}";  ==> char left = '}';
*String right = "{"; ==> char right = '{';
```

Change your condition for the second if statement

```
*if(left) ==> if(brackets.charAt(i) == left)
```